# Not getting data in phtml file in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have override `email/shipment/items.phtml` in custom module.
in `view/frontend/sales_email_order_shipment_items.xml`






Vendor_module::email/shipment/items.phtml

I am not getting any data on printing $shipment = $block->getShipment();

Is their any thing missing?

Comment: please specify layout file name.

Comment: sales_email_order_shipment_items.xml

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try This**

**sales_email_order_shipment_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Shipment Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <update handle="sales_email_order_shipment_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Shipment\Items" name="items" template="Vendor_module::email/shipment/items.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.email.order.shipment.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
        </block>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: <update handle="sales_email_order_shipment_renderers"/> &             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.email.order.shipment.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
 Is necessary to add ?

Comment: Yes it's necessary to add. It's works for you ?

Comment: yes it works, but can you please explain why its necessary to add ?
& also why settemplate layout is  not working with it ?

Comment: ya sure, it would be great if you please explain why its necessary to add ? & also why settemplate layout is not working with it ?

Comment: I am not getting shipmentid in phtml file.
at the same time i get it in vendor file